# Split ssh config by Host using lua

Tags: lua

I want to parse ssh config file on linux to get the information (Hostname, user) for each Host defined in *$HOME/.ssh/config*. My idea is to use lua *string.gmatch* to split the file using Host as a delimiter, but for some reason the pattern matching does not work. Here is the code from the lua interpreter

```
> =x
Host h1
Hostname ip1
User root
Host h2 h3
Hostname ip2
User admin
Host *
ControlPath xyz 

> for i in x:gmatch('(Host%s+.-)Host%s') do print(i) end
Host h1
Hostname ip1
User root

>
```

Comment: How to split: `for i in x:gsub('%f[^%z\n]Host%s', '\0%0'):gmatch('%Z+') do`

Answer (score 0):

Capture the hostname value consisting of alphanumerics including dot, hyphen and underscore.

```
x = [[Host h1
Hostname ip1
Host h2
Hostname ip2

Host *
ControlMaster auto]]

for i in x:gmatch("Hostname%s+([%w%.-_]+)") do
  print(i)
end
```

Comment: The ssh config contains both Host and User..My example does not show user...but my intent was to capture both hostname and user for a single host. Your solution capture hostname and not the Host.

Comment: Have you tried my solution? It surely captures the host value and not the Hostname key. Or just substitute Hostname by Host or User.

Comment: I need mapping between host and information.. h1 --> ip1, root and h2 --> ip2, admin. I have updated the example in the question as well

Answer (score 0):

Here is my complete solution to your problem. It reads the input file from STDIN. Run it like e.g.: `program.lua < /path/to/.ssh/config`

```
--Example of SSH config file
--[[
Host h1
HostName ip1
User root
Host h2 h3
Hostname ip2
User admin
Host *
ControlPath xyz
--]]

local hostPattern = "Host%s+([%w%.-_]+)"
local hostNamePattern = "Host[Nn]ame%s+([%w%.-_]+)"
local userPattern = "User%s+([%w%.-_]+)"

local line = io.read("l")
while line do
    if line:find(hostPattern) then
        local host = line:match(hostPattern)
        local hostName, user

        line = io.read("l")
        while line do
            if line:find(hostPattern) then
                break
            elseif line:find(hostNamePattern) then
                hostName = line:match(hostNamePattern)
            elseif line:find(userPattern) then
                user = line:match(userPattern)
            end
            line = io.read("l")
        end
        io.write(string.format("%s: -> %s, %s", host, hostName, user))
    end
    io.write("\n")
end
```

And this is the output you can expect:

```
h1: -> ip1, root
h2: -> ip2, admin
```